# Ruby https requests with headers

Tags: ruby

How do you do an https request with ruby that also has headers, with the builtin module, I've read docs did some tries and did some googling no luck, if someone can help that would be appreciated.

Code I've tried

```
require 'net/http'
data = Net::HTTP.get("https://urlhere.com")
data['Authorization'] = @token
res = http.request(data)
return res.body
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Please show this code and describe what was send/received.

Comment: Step one: Read the docs. Step two: Write some code. Step three: If you're having trouble with that code, include the code in your question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I did try and read docs, i just edited the post with an example i used.

Comment: What error do you get?  That's how you specify headers in a request.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but i solved it already. Basically it was trying to use a host port thing, so i used uri for that and a way different way to request found in a tutorial.